# What is the spin of an electron along the x-axis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, electrons, measurements

I know that an electron or any other particle for that matter, has a measured spin which is either up or down. This spin is along the z-axis. But what if we do not measure it along the z-axis and do it along the x-axis instead. What will the result be?

Will it get deflected along the x-axis in a Stern Gerlach experiment?
Lastly, will it always get deflected along the axis we measure its spin?

Answer (score 3):

Up or down, obviously. However, the representation of the x-up state or the x-down state using z-up and z-down states depends on how you represent the spin operator. For the most favoured choice

$S_x=\frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$

gives up/down state as (not normalised)

$\left|x_{up}\right>=\left( \begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\end{array} \right), \left|x_{down}\right>=\left( \begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\end{array} \right)$

Comment: So will the electron get deflected in a Stern Gerlach experiment along the x-axis? And sorry I do not understand Pauli Matrices.

Comment: Yep. They get deflected along the x-axis. Try volume 3 of Feynman Lecture series or Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: Pauli matrices are nothing more than a method of representing the spin of a particle with spin half. When distinct states are finite in number, we can use linear algebra to represent and calculate the physical system. That is what Pauli matrices do.

Answer (score 3):

It's important that the spin need not be up or down, but may be in some superposition of the two, $|\psi\rangle = a |\uparrow\rangle+b|\downarrow\rangle$. If you choose to measure it in the $z$-direction, the squared magnitudes of $a$ and $b$ will give relative probabilities of getting each answer.

But given any direction, you can always rewrite the state as a superposition of up and down spin in that direction instead (technical bit: the up and down are the eigenstates of $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$ where $\vec{n}$ is the unit direction vector and $\vec{\sigma}$ the Pauli matrices). There will now be different probabilities associated to the possible outcomes of the measurement. For example, if the original state had definite spin up in the $z$-direction, $|\psi\rangle = |\uparrow\rangle$, the probability of getting 'up' when measuring the spin in a direction at an angle $\theta$ to the $z$-axis will be $\cos^2(\theta/2)$.

Comment: But if we measure it along the x-axis, then will the deflection also be along the x-axis? I am talking about the Stern Gerlach experiment. Thanks. Unfortunately I do not understand Pauli Matrices and the measurement angle part. All I need to know at the moment is that will the electron deflect along the x-axis.

Comment: Yes, Stern-Gerlach is one way of measuring the spin. The particle will be deflected in a direction aligned with the applied magnetic field, in whichever direction you choose to put that applied field.

Comment: So we can in a way say that the particle obtains the poles according to our measurement. Unless we measure it, it has all the poles in all directions?